# How to create multirow and multicolumn RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a recyclerview that have rows and columns. Each item contains user's avatar and user's name like so:.

```
   (ImageView)
   (TextView)
```

The layout of the wanted recyclerview:

```
[] [] [] []
[] [] [] []
[] [] [] []
[] []
```

The example contains 14 items. I want the screen to fit to the number of objects that can fit in the row. So if the width of the screen is less than the previous example, then we get something like:

```
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] []
```

I have experience with both horizontal and vertical recyclerview separately, but how do I combine?

Comment: Perhaps with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridLayoutManager to achieve this. Just set the layoutManager for the recyclerview to be GridLayoutManager. You can also specify spanCount to be equal to the number of columns you want in a row.